# Include Third Party Jars ANT

Tags: eclipse, ant, jar

I am new to using ANT and am trying to include third party jars in the build using Eclipse 3.5. I keep getting "cannot find symbol" errors in the compilation, so obviously it is not taking these two jars into consideration. If anyone can show me where I am going wrong, or suggest another route, I would appreciate it.

JarPath below is the path to my project in the Eclipse workspace. It tried '/' and '\' in the path and neither mattered.

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<project default="main">
    <property name="env.JAVA_HOME" location="C:\Program Files\Java\jdk\bin\javac.exe"/>
    <property name="jars.dir" location="JarPath"/>

    <target name="main" depends="compile, compress" description="Main target">
        <echo>
            Building the .jar file.
        </echo>
    </target>

    <target name="compile" description="Compilation target">
        <javac srcdir="." fork="yes" executable="${env.JAVA_HOME}"/>
        <classpath>        
            <pathelement location="${jars.dir}/A.jar"/>        
            <pathelement location="${jars.dir}/B.jar"/>    
        </classpath>
    </target>

  <target name="compress" description="Compression target">
        <jar jarfile="MyJar.jar" basedir="." includes="*.class" />
  </target>
</project>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I always use a nested fileset element inside the classpath element.  You can specify specific files or use globbing.  It should look something likethis:

```
<classpath id="classpath" description="The default classpath.">
  <pathelement path="${classpath}"/>
  <fileset dir="lib">
    <include name="jaxp.jar"/>
    <include name="crimson.jar"/>
    <include name="ojdbc14.jar"/>
  </fileset>
</classpath>
```

You can also use the include element to glob, ie

```
<include name="*.jar/>
```

So you can include any jar.

Comment: Thanks a lot. One problem was if you notice above my classpath tag is not within the javac tag. once i move it within there it did compile. It compiles using your method too.

Answer (score 0):

I think this also works. "classpath" should be put into "javac"

```
<target name="compile" description="Compilation target">
    <javac srcdir="." fork="yes" executable="${env.JAVA_HOME}">
        <classpath>        
            <path location="${jars.dir}/A.jar"/>        
            <path location="${jars.dir}/B.jar"/>    
        </classpath>
    </javac>
</target>
```